# How many calories are burnt by walking upstairs with a 30kg (66 pounds) backpack and ankle weights?

Tags: cardio, calories, stairs

I train for mountaineering by walking upstairs as described in the question's title. The ankle weights are 2kg each (about 4.5 pounds). I am 75kg (165 pounds), 178cm (5'8").

I am very interested in how many calories may such an effort burn per hour. I know it's quite an uncommon exercise, but an estimate based on some sound information would help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use the "climbing hills" activity for the closest approximation to what you're describing. Climbing hills with minimal weight (9 lbs or less) will burn around 500 calories per hour at your body weight.

If you increase the weight to 20 - 40 lbs, then you will be closer to 575 calories burned per hour.

When carrying over 42 lbs, then you will be around 650 calories burned per hour.

[Source](http://www.nutristrategy.com/caloriesburnedwalking.htm)